# Http failure during parsing for http... while downloading pdf file

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am new to angular and I have been struggling to figure out how to download a file, in my case a pdf file.
This is the error I get:

```
Http failure during parsing for https://url...
```

In the debug console of the browser the is also an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse
```

Actually I am downloading a pdf file. Here is how my http call looks like:

```
  protected get<T>(url: string, params: any, defaultResult: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient.get<T>(url, {
    headers: myHeader,
    params: params
})
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError(defaultResult))
  );
```

}
How

Comment: Is the server returning a pdf? Are you parsing it as JSON?

Comment: Hi @Carsten, yes the server is returning a pdf. I'm not doing any parsing. Angular seems to do it on its own.

Comment: That's correct. Angular parses json by default. So you can search google on how to change that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are passing back a blob of data rather than JSON but not letting the httpclient know how to parse it back, angular is trying to parse response back as a JSON which is the default path.

Here is documentation from the angular website:

```
request(first: string | HttpRequest<any>, url?: string, options: {
    body?: any;
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: HttpObserve;
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
} = {}): Observable<any>
```

**responseType:**

**In addition to configuring request parameters such as the outgoing headers and/or the body, the options hash specifies two key pieces of information about the request: the responseType and what to observe.
The responseType value determines how a successful response body will be parsed. If responseType is the default json, a type interface for the resulting object may be passed as a type parameter to request().**

So in your case try:

```
    protected get<T>(url: string, params: any, defaultResult: T): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get(url, {
        headers: myHeader,
        params: params,
        responseType: 'blob'
    })
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError(defaultResult))
      );
```

more info:

[httpclient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)

[documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)

Similar question
[Angular HttpClient "Http failure during parsing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408537/angular-httpclient-http-failure-during-parsing/46408622)

Comment: In order to get this to work, I had to return the type declaration after post.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just forgot to add the request options for the http client
**before**

```js
public downloadSummaryByMat(mat:string){
    return this.http.get(this.url+'/reports/'+mat);
  }
```

**after**

```js
public downloadSummaryByMat(mat:string){
    return this.http.get(this.url+'/reports/'+mat,{ responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

working for me thank you 
For component please check below

```
downloadFile(caseID) {
    console.log(caseID);
    this.mediaService.downloadFile(caseID).subscribe(
        (downloaded) => {
        console.log('File is Downloaded', downloaded);
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(downloaded);
        window.open(url);
    });
}
```

Comment: Show me the this.mediaService.downloadFile() service