# TypeError: res.blob is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to implement file download using this Angular 6 code:

Rest API:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadsController.class);

@GetMapping(path="export") 
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> export() throws IOException {
    File pdfFile = Paths.get(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH).toFile();


    byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(pdfFile.toPath());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    // Here you have to set the actual filename of your pdf
    String filename = "output.pdf";
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(fileContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/index";
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import {HttpUtils} from "../common/http-utils";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Http, ResponseContentType} from '@angular/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DownloadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  downloadPDF(): any {
    return this.http.get(environment.api.urls.downloads.getPdf, {
        responseType: 'blob'
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          return new Blob([res.blob()], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
          })
        })
      );
    }  
}
```

Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DownloadService} from "../service/download.service";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {flatMap} from "rxjs/internal/operators";
import {of} from "rxjs/index";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-download',
  templateUrl: './download.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./download.component.scss']
})
export class DownloadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private downloadService: DownloadService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
  }

  export() {               
    this.downloadService.downloadPDF().subscribe(res => {
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
      window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
    });         
  } 
}
```

The file is present in the directory but when I try to download it I get error:

```
ERROR TypeError: res.blob is not a function
    at MapSubscriber.project (download.service.ts:24)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:38)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:84)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?
Do I need to add additional configuration in order to download the file via Angular web UI?

I use spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.1.0.RELEASE and angular 6

Update: I tested this but nothing happens:

```
downloadPDF(): any {
    return this.http.get(environment.api.urls.downloads.getPdf, {
        responseType: 'blob'
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          return new Blob([res], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
          })
        })
      );
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to call `.blob()` on it if you pass the responseType like you have. It should already be a blob

Comment: @user184994 I updated the code but nothing happens when I press the button. Any idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: Is your browser trying to block the popup or anything? Add a few `console.log` in the code to find out how far its getting

Comment: Ok, it turns out that blocker is causing the problem. Is there some way to avoid it?

Comment: Ok, this line is the problem: `return new Blob([res.blob()], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
          })` Should I use new Blob?

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2> <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018730/http-failure-during-parsing-for-http-while-downloading-pdf-file>

Comment: Please refer these links. * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018730/http-failure-during-parsing-for-http-while-downloading-pdf-file

Answer (score 7):

Use the `res.body` instead of `res` while constructing the `Blob`.

```
downloadPDF(): any {
    return this.http.get(environment.api.urls.downloads.getPdf, {
        responseType: 'blob'
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          return new Blob([res.body], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
          })
        })
      );
    }
```

Comment: It's correct. I suppose that something is missing into the typescript code?

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: try once with `res._body` instead of `res.body`