# Httpclient request in angular json error

Tags: json, angular, http, newrelic

I am doing http client request

```
export class MapjsonService{
  theUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/api/Lat_Long.json';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchNews(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.theUrl)
  }
```

It is working about 99.99% of the time sadly this is running so often that is fails like once every 10 mins with

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/Lat_Long.json", ok: false, …}
```

and

```
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/api/Lat_Long.json"
```

Now I figured out for some reason my nrql query from newrelic (which is what is being stored in '/api/lat_long.json' does not have the final closing '}' once every orange moon. and this is what is throwing this error.  my question is there any whay for me to check if the returned value is valid json and if it is not try the `GET` request again without terminating the process that called it.  Thx

Comment: This question is sort of like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408537/angular-httpclient-http-failure-during-parsing) exept I am have a json file that sometimes is'nt

Comment: By adding `, {responseType: 'text'}` parameter to the `http.get` function you will receive the response as text, you can then try to decode the json in a `try{}catch(){}`

Comment: @Ploppy is there not just a way to make a custem error ketcher for parsing errors.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: *snif* I was hopping not to have to do try{}catch(){} thing but I guess it is going to be necessary.

Comment: @Ploppy I actually don't even see how I can do that since I need to return a observible

Comment: Ok I will write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is throwing an error because the json is not correct, therefore it can't be parsed, and therefore the observable throws an error:

```
fetchNews(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(this.theUrl)
}
```

By default, the http client expect json because that's usually what users expect from it. It's not always the case, like the situation you are in right now.

We can tell the http client not to parse the json on its own by specifying what we want from it using the `{responseType: 'text'}` parameter.

```
fetchNews(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(this.theUrl, {responseType: 'text'})
}
```

But then you need to parse the json when possible. So we will map the observable and parse the content here if possible.

```
fetchNews(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(this.theUrl, {responseType: 'text'}).map(res => {
    try{ 
      return JSON.parse(res); 
    } catch {
      return null;
    }
  })
}
```

Then do whatever you want, the value returned by the observable will be `null` if it can't be parsed.

---

RXJS 6 syntax:

```
fetchNews(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(this.theUrl, {responseType: 'text'}).pipe(
    map(res => {
      try{ 
        return JSON.parse(res); 
      } catch {
        return null;
      }
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Ah what I was doing wrong was I forgot the `.map(...)` part sorry i'm very new to angular thanks so much it works.

Comment: Observable are not complexe, though I think they are unintuitive. Once you get them you will be able to take full advantage of them and won't even think of coding without it!

Comment: Note that with RXJS 6 the syntax would change slightly. I will edit the answer accordingly.