# Angular6 http.get result to string

Tags: angular, typescript

I make a Get call to my API and want the result as a string so I can split it

```
  GetServiceProviderId() {
   this.http.get(this.rooturl + 'info', { headers: this.reqHeader });

    var data = "mitId: 18, ServiceProvider: 2" <- result I get and want to split
    var dataspilitted = data.split(" ");
    return dataspilitted[3];
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HttpClient "Http failure during parsing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408537/angular-httpclient-http-failure-during-parsing)

Answer (score 3):

[Original guide](https://angular.io/guide/http)
says you need to specify responseType in request options

```
GetServiceProviderId() {
    return this.http.get(this.rooturl + 'info', { headers: this.reqHeader, responseType:'text' })
        .map(data => {
    var dataspilitted = data.split(" ");
    return dataspilitted[3];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that a JSON response? Why convert to string, split, get the 3rd word, convert to number and hope that nothing changes?

you could just do:

```
this.http.get(this.rooturl + 'info', { headers: this.reqHeader })
  .subscribe(result => console.log('Result is ', result.ServiceProvider));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to subscribe to the HTTP call and then parse the data from the response depending on how it is formatted.

```
GetServiceProviderId() {
    this.http.get(this.rooturl + 'info', { headers: this.reqHeader }).subscribe(
        (data) => {
            // Optionally parse "data" into string depending on result format
            // data = parse(data)
            this.dataSplit = data.split(" ")[3];
        }
    );
}
```

In this example `parse(data)` is some function that you would write to parse the data into a string, if the HTTP response does not return a string in the first place.