# Angular 6 Unable to read Octet-stream in HttpClient Error message: "Http failure during parsing for..."

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I want to make non-json request to server using angular 6 HttpClient (@angular/common/http) to get Octet-stream . Below is my code.

```
getFile(file: any) {
    let headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/octet-stream',
        'Accept':'application/octet-stream',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data.token
    })

    return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + '/getfile/'+file, headers);
}
```

But this gives me JSON parse error.

> "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for.....
>   ERROR 
>   {…}
>   ​
>   error: {…}
>   ​​
>   error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Whats the way to read it as non-json?

Comment: `this.http.get(..., { responseType: 'text' })` may be what you need. What are you going to use the result for?

Comment: I want to download it as a file. ALso I'm passing authorization through header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HttpClient "Http failure during parsing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408537/angular-httpclient-http-failure-during-parsing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data.token
    });
return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + '/getfile/'+file, {headers:headers, responseType: 'blob'});
```