# When Updating to HttpClient: Uncaught in Promise/Http Failure during parsing

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, httpclient

In my angular app I'm updating from Http to HttpClient, which doesn't seem to work when working with Promises.

It seems like you need to use a little 'work-around' when dealing with promises in the httpClient, I tried to do it like in this article: https://vitalflux.com/angular-promise-explained-code-example/ but to no avail.

I also tried to work with Observable instead (and subscribe in the component.ts), but this also did not work out.

---

service.ts (**with old Http**, works like a charm)

```
public viewPDF(profileId: string, profileVersion: Date): Promise<any> {
    const pdfVersion = _.split(_.replace(profileVersion.toISOString(), /:/g, '-'), '.')[0];

    return this.http
      .get(`${this.pdfApiView}/${profileId}/${pdfVersion}`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response);
  }
```

service.ts (-- now **with HttpClient**)

```
  public viewPDF(profileId: string, profileVersion: Date): Promise<any> {
    const pdfVersion = _.split(_.replace(profileVersion.toISOString(), /:/g, '-'), '.')[0];

    return this.httpClient
      .get<any>(`${this.pdfApiView}/${profileId}/${pdfVersion}`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response);
  }
```

component.ts

```
 this.pdfDocumentService.viewPDF(prof[0].id, prof[0].version).then(resp => {
      if (resp._body !== 'file not found') {
        this.pdfList.set(prof[0].id + prof[0].version, resp.url);
      }
 });
```

The new method lead to the following Error messages:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse:
> {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":200,"statusText":"OK","url":"http://localhost:4200/api/pdfFile/i1cib1pgvk000000/2019-04-02T12-47-57","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure during parsing for
> http://localhost:4200/api/pdfFile/i1cib1pgvk000000/2019-04-02T12-47-57","error":{"error":{},"text":"%PDF-1.3\n%����\n6
> 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Page\n/Parent 1 0 R\n/MediaBox ...

Comment: If you are working with files, you may need `{ responseType: 'blob' }` ([info](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#responseType))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HttpClient "Http failure during parsing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408537/angular-httpclient-http-failure-during-parsing)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, this is what worked:

```
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.pdfApiView}/${profileId}/${pdfVersion}`, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob',
    });
```

I also needed to omit the casting (post)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use .then() .toPromise(), just look at this example.

In your service.

```
getData(): Observable<any> {

    let body: any = {};

    const options = { responseType: 'blob' };

    const url = `your api url`;

    return this._http.post<any>( url, body, options );
}
```

and then consume

```
this._service.getData().subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
```