# Angular http.post() gives: "error 415 unsupported MIME type"

Tags: angular, http, sparql, mime, graphdb

**Hello and thanks for reading,**

The context of the problem is that I'm trying to send a SPARQL query from an Angular web application to a GraphDB server (on a specific URL:128.199.58.129:7200 using a virtual machine to run).

However, everytime i try to use the script(button) further below, i get the following error:

[image: error]

Here is the script:

```
cando(event){
    const body = "query=CONSTRUCT+%7B%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%7D+WHERE+%7B%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%7D+LIMIT+10"
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/x-trig').set("Content-Type",'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = { headers:HttpHeaders};
    var url = "http://128.199.58.129:7200/repositories/repo/statements";
    this.http.request("post",url,{body:body,headers:headers}).toPromise().then(function(response){
      console.log(response.toString());
    });
  }
```

The same script in image form for legibility:
[image]

If anyone could shed some light on this, would be extremely helpful! I have been looking at other threads with the same error but they usually don't apply to web applications or their solutions don't work. Will update if I find something.

- Tried different MIME types, but they yield the same result.
- Edited the "mime.types" document present in the /etc folder of the Virtual machine and adding application/x-www-form-urlencoded to the list.
- Tried using the http.request() method to send the query
- Tried different types of encoding/contenttypes, but those give error 400: malformed data: invalid subject

Comment: `update=` not `query=` http://docs.rdf4j.org/rest-api/#_perform_update_described_in_a_sparql_1_1_update_string. Also do request as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45962083/1527544

Comment: @Antoniossss "update" is used for insert queries and such, as this is a select or construct query, it simply uses "query=". Tried doing it using URLSearchparams still gives the 415 error. code below


`cando(event){
    let body = new URLSearchParams()
    body.set("query","construct%20{?s%20?p%20?o}%20where%20{?s%20?p%20?o}");
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/x-trig').set("Content-Type",'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http.request("post",url,{body:body.toString(),headers:headers}).toPromise().then(function(response){}`

Comment: @AndrewMalcolm Are you sure that the repository URL is correct? Right now, you're using `http://128.199.58.129:7200/repositories/repo/statements` but this is, afaik, used for the REST service only. Can you try just `http://128.199.58.129:7200/repositories/repo/` instead?

Comment: @AKSW *afaik, used for the REST service only.* so it cannot be used from Anuglar?

Comment: @Antoniossss What do you mean? RDF4J has repositories and for each it provides access via SPARQL or other specific REST API service. All of them are done via REST of course. Of course you can use Angular, but depending on the the request (SPARQL query or some other REST service) you have to use the correct URL.  [/RDF4J_Server_URL/REPO_NAME/Statements](http://docs.rdf4j.org/rest-api/#_repository_statements) is limited in what it can do, and in particular for POST

Comment: @Antoniossss *"POST: **Performs updates** on the data in the repository. The data supplied with this request is expected to contain either an RDF document, a **SPARQL 1.1 Update** string, or a special purpose transaction document. If an RDF document is supplied, the statements found in the RDF document will be added to the repository. If a SPARQL 1.1 Update string is supplied, the update operation will be parsed and executed. If a transaction document is supplied, the updates specified in the transaction document will be executed."*

Comment: So, you can't use a query here, just use `/RDF4J_Server_URL/REPO_NAME` as URL and it should work

Comment: @AKSW and Antoniossss , Thank you both, you guys were correct I need to simply use /server_URL/repositories/Repository_name as url. 

Afterwards I got the HTTP failure error 200, saying it couldnt parse the new repository URL. But this was quickly solved by following the answer in this thread:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408537/angular-httpclient-http-failure-during-parsing)

Basically adding a legible "responsetype" parameter to the POST method. Thank you very much!