# Load HTML and CSS from API get with Angular 10+

Tags: angular

Is there any recommended method on Angular 10+ to load the HTML and CSS for a component from an HTTP call to a web API?
I try this code

`<div [innherHtml]="bodyHtml | async"></div>`

my component:

```
bodyHtml: any
constructor() {
 this.bodyHtml = yourContentService.GetContent()
}
```

my service:

```
GetContent() {
    const uri = `http://localhost:3000/api/books/`;
    return this.http.get(uri, {headers :{'Accept': 'text/html', 'responseType': 'text' as 'json'}});
  }
```

but I got this error:
`message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/api/books/"`
I need help plz and thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular HttpClient "Http failure during parsing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408537/angular-httpclient-http-failure-during-parsing) - your `responseType` looks invalid. Try just `'text'` instead of `'text' as 'json'`.

Comment: I make the change and still the same error

Comment: responseType needs to be outside the headers object literal.

Comment: working fine now ty ty