# Getting "Http failure during parsing" - Trying to mimic a slow API to show importance of Async-Await

Tags: angular

I'm using [Dummy APIs](https://dummyapis.com/) to demonstrate importance of Asyn-await while handling a delayed server response. Simple thing is if i make a get call to this URL (https://hub.dummyapis.com/delay?seconds=3) I'll be getting a response i.e. "This response has been delayed for 3 seconds" after 3 seconds. But my Promise is always rejecting. Here is my code:

**Service**

```
constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

getHeroes(): Observable<any> {
  return this._httpClient.get('https://hub.dummyapis.com/delay?seconds=3');
}
```

**Component TS file**

```
  error: string = 'Oops! something went wrong';

  async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      let x = await this.fetchData();
      // this.heroes = [...x];
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log("I've received an error: ", error.message);
    }
  }

  async fetchData(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._heroListService.getHeroes().subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          if (typeof res === 'object') {
            resolve(res.text()); // Converting the response in string format
          } else {
            reject(new Error('Invalid response format')); // Reject if the response is not in the expected format
          }
        },
        (error: any) => {
          reject(error); // Reject with the error
        },
        () => {
          console.log('Call complete!');
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

I checked on my network call also. The API is working correctly. Status is "200 OK" and there is a response also:

[image]

What else I'm missing here. Please point out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging which of the two `reject` is called?

Comment: yes, its always the second reject.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular HttpClient "Http failure during parsing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408537/angular-httpclient-http-failure-during-parsing)

Comment: Per default angular tries to parse the response as JSON, which will give an error if the response is not JSON...

Comment: @derpirscher, yes it helped me solve my problem, though it was not the accepted answer that helped but i got help from Martin's answer on scrolling down little it.

Answer (score 0):

I knew that something is wrong with the format of the response. It is not JSON so i was using:

```
(res: any) => {
  if (typeof res === 'object') {
    resolve(res.text()); // Converting the response in string format
  } else {
    reject(new Error('Invalid response format')); // Reject if the response is not in the expected format
  }
 }
```

What i should be doing is adding responseType in my get calld as follows:

```
getHeroes(): Observable<any> {
  return this._httpClient.get('https://hub.dummyapis.com/delay?seconds=3',
  {responseType: 'text',}); // response type needs to be told first
}
```