# Observable<string | ArrayBuffer> is not assignable to type Observable<string> when responseType='text'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a REST endpoint that returns a string.

If I don't specify a responseType  in the request then Angular fails to parse the response as it assumes that it is json.

If I specify the responseType as 'text' then the typescript transpiler (and WebStorm IDE) both complain that

```
Observable<string | ArrayBuffer> is not assignable to type Observable<string>
```

How can I configure the request so that

1. It knows that it should expect a plain string back
2. It doesn't complain when transpiling?

```
    getCusto4merEmail() : Observable<string> {
        const path : string = `${this.loginResource}/getCustomerEmail`;
        return this.http.get<string>(path, {responseType: 'text'});
    }
```

- This answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408622/493682
- As well as [this Angular doco](https://angular.io/guide/http-request-data-from-server#the-observe-and-responsetype-options) suggest that I just need to provide
  'responseType: 'text'}

But it gives the transpile error above.

Comment: What if you omit the return type when calling `get`. Like this: `http.get(path, {responseType: 'text'})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods of the [HttpClient](https://angular.dev/api/common/http/HttpClient/) are heavily overloaded to enable easy inference of the return type.

In your case just setting the `responseType` to `text` will force `Observable<string>`:

```
return this.httpClient.get(path, {responseType: 'text'});
```

What you tried didn't work because the `responseType:'text'` method doesn't specify a generic :

```
get(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    context?: HttpContext;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: 'text';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
    transferCache?: {
        includeHeaders?: string[];
    } | boolean;
}): Observable<string>;
```

Which is why the compiler is falling back to one of the signature with `Observable<ArrayBuffer>`